# Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('S32') according to the rule 'safe' ON Model_result=model.predict(classify)

Tags: python, prediction

I'm trying to run a python program but get an error. This code is to predict the values and classify it. It works on a GradientBoostingClassifier model but not with a LinearSVC() class model.

This code is used to create the model for the output class:

```
data_file=pd.read_csv('C:\\Class.csv')
testx = data_file.iloc[0:, :5]
testy= data_file.iloc[0:, 5]
model = make_pipeline(LinearSVC())
model.fit(testx,testy)
import pickle
filename = 'C:\\Model\\svm.sav'
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

---

See the below code which has an error when using the the linearSVC output class model

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
time=0.0
print "\n"
time = input(" \t Please Enter Time in Mili Seconds (Ms): ")
print "\n"
#Data-Read
filename1 = 'c:\\Model\\HR_model.sav'
filename2 = 'c:\\Model\\SpO2_model.sav'
filename3 = 'c:\\Model\\SYS_model.sav'
filename4 = 'c:\\Model\\Dia_model.sav'
filename5 = 'c:\\Model\\Mean_model.sav'
filename6 = 'c:\\Model\\svm.sav'
classify=list()
HR = pickle.load(open(filename1, 'rb'))
hr_result=HR.predict(time)
classify.append(str(float(hr_result)))
SPO2 = pickle.load(open(filename2, 'rb'))
SPO2_result=SPO2.predict(time)
classify.append(str(float(SPO2_result)))
Sys = pickle.load(open(filename3, 'rb'))
Sys_result=Sys.predict(time)
classify.append(str(float(Sys_result)))
DIA = pickle.load(open(filename4, 'rb'))
DIA_result=DIA.predict(time)
classify.append(str(float(DIA_result)))
MEan = pickle.load(open(filename5, 'rb'))
MEan_result=MEan.predict(time)
classify.append(str(float(MEan_result)))


#Classifier train Model
model = pickle.load(open(filename6, 'rb'))
Model_result=model.predict(classify)
print "\n"

print "Input Features:"
print classify 
print "\n"
print "Output Class: "
print Model_result
```

---

Upon running the program, I get the following error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last) C:\ForcastPredictFromModels.py in ()   50 #CLassifier
>   train Model  51 model = pickle.load(open(filename6, 'rb'))  ---> 52
>   Model_result=model.predict(classify)  53 print "\n"  54
>
> C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-
>   packages\sklearn\utils\metaestimators.pyc in (*args, **kwargs)
>   52   53         # lambda, but not partial, allows help() to work with 
>   update_wrapper  ---> 54         out = lambda *args, **kwargs:
>   self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)  55         # update the docstring of
>   the returned function  56         update_wrapper(out, self.fn)
>
> C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-
>   packages\sklearn\pipeline.pyc in predict(self, X) 325             if
>   transform is not None: 326                 Xt =
>   transform.transform(Xt)
>   --> 327         return self.steps[-1][-1].predict(Xt) 328  329     @if_delegate_has_method(delegate='_final_estimator')
>
> C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.pyc
>   in predict(self, X) 334             Predicted class label per sample.
>   335         """
>   --> 336         scores = self.decision_function(X) 337         if len(scores.shape) == 1: 338             indices = (scores >
>   0).astype(np.int)
>
> C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.pyc
>   in decision_function(self, X) 318  319         scores =
>   safe_sparse_dot(X, self.coef_.T,
>   --> 320                                  dense_output=True) + self.intercept_ 321         return scores.ravel() if scores.shape[1]
>   == 1 else scores 322
>
> C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.pyc
>   in safe_sparse_dot(a, b, dense_output) 187         return ret 188
>   else:
>   --> 189         return fast_dot(a, b) 190  191
>
> TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to
>   dtype('S32') according to the rule 'safe'